# Часовой пояс в Date

Tags: java

Класс `Date` в Java может возвращать время в миллисекундах, а из какой timezone он возвращает, текущей или из UTC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Объект Data возвращает вам системное время вашей **виртуальной машины**. Т.е , раскрывая вопрос полностью, время с учетом вашей таймзоны.

> **[Локальное системное время (системное время)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzati/rzatitime.htm?lang=ru)**
>   Локальное системное время
>   получается путем прибавления к временем по Гринвичу указанных в
>   часовом поясе системы значений разности с временем по Гринвичу и
>   разности лет. Системное значение времени суток содержит именно
>   локальное системное время. Понятия системного времени и локального
>   системного времени эквивалентны.

Проверить данное утверждение Вы можете вызвав

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

И раскопав в src как реализован данный метод...

**UPD** В ответ на комментарий автора.
[офф. документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) обратите внимание на следующие строчки:

> Although the Date class is intended to reflect [coordinated universal
>   time (UTC)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), it may not do so exactly, depending on the host
>   environment of the Java Virtual Machine. Nearly all modern operating
>   systems assume that 1 day = 24 × 60 × 60 = 86400 seconds in all cases.
>   In UTC, however, about once every year or two there is an extra
>   second, called a "leap second." The leap second is always added as the
>   last second of the day, and always on December 31 or June 30. For
>   example, the last minute of the year 1995 was 61 seconds long, thanks
>   to an added leap second. Most computer clocks are not accurate enough
>   to be able to reflect the leap-second distinction.

помимо интересной информации о второй поправке времени.Вы можете обнаружить что объект типа Date предоставляет Вам время в формате *Coordinated Universal Time*...

Comment: Где то читал что Date.getTime() возвращает время в милисекундах от 1 января 1970 года и таймзона всегда по умолчанию UTC 0, я вот не помню так ли это на самом деле или мне так показалось

Answer (score 6):

Местное. (То что на твоем ПК)

Сейчас за это отвечает другой класс - `Calendar`

Answer (score 3):

Объект `Data` возвращает вам системное время вашей машины и только. Можно программно изменить время на машине.

```
Date dataCurrent=new Date();

System.out.println(dataCurrent);

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));  

Date dataNewZone=new Date();

System.out.println(dataNewZone);
```

Вывод программы

> Wed Sep 21 17:47:40 MSK 2016
>
> Wed Sep 21 07:47:40 PDT 2016

Время в милисекундах одинаково для всех часовых поясов.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` не хранит информацию о временной зоне, всегда используется только текущая временная зона, которая берётся из OC. Если нужно хранить значение временной зоны, то следует использовать класс `java.util.Calendar` см. [setTimeZone(TimeZone value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) и [getTimeZone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeZone%28%29)